# How to maintain opened a chrome extension popup or a detached window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension (my first one), and according to the documentation, a popup will always close when lost its focus. But I am seeing some extension that maintain opened the window even when you click in another place or you refresh the page. For example, google hangouts:

[image: screenshot of Google Hangout Extension]

As you can see, the window is a detached one, but I cannot figure it out how they did it. I have been reading the documentation but they do not mention anything similar. Also, I have not found any similar techniques on google or even here. Any of you knows how Google did this?
The extension I am developing needs to be always opened when the user is recollecting info.

My thanks in advance

Comment: Use chrome.windows.create

Answer (score 0):

The solution, mentioned by @wOxxOm, was to use `chrome.windows.create`